# Syntax Error in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
INTO Temp3

from

( SELECT B.Name
FROM [Temp2] as B 
WHERE B.Name
Not IN (
SELECT E.WorkerName
FROM WorkerDetail as E ) )
```

Why does this produce an error?

Comment: Complete Sentences and Good Formating always Help :)

Comment: You will have to post all the table creation scripts too.

Comment: Hello, jame, are you there? Did you just ask the question and run away?

Comment: my given query does not work ......why?I want to insert value in temp3

Comment: jame, please edit your question and show us the error you see.

Comment: Also, what are you using?  MSSQL Server? MySql? SQLite? Oracle? something else?

Comment: @jame: what is the error message?

Comment: He just put up a second question exactly like this one.

Comment: @jame: is there someone you work with who could help you answer?

Comment: @jame: ist es jemand Sie mit arbeiten, die Ihnen helfen könnte beantworten?

Comment: It's been an hour. I'm voting to close as not a real question. Maybe he can find an interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a derived table you need to alias it:

```
SELECT T1.*
INTO Temp3

from

( SELECT B.Name
FROM [Temp2] as B 
WHERE B.Name
Not IN (
SELECT E.WorkerName
FROM WorkerDetail as E ) )  AS T1
```

I'm not sure if you actually need to use a derived table, however.

This should also work:

```
SELECT B.Name
INTO Temp3
FROM [Temp2] as B 
WHERE B.Name
Not IN (
SELECT E.WorkerName
FROM WorkerDetail as E )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Temp3 already exists? 
In MSSQL SELECT..INTO used to populate new table with data.
If this table exist, you can use INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM statement.